# Can't seem to get Angular 2 rc4 working with Foundation 6.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, zurb-foundation

So I am just using cdn's for the Foundation 6 stuff for now as I wanted to quickly test the foundation Topnav - below is the index.html of my angular 2 app

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <base href=".">
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.min.css"> 

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I created a new angular 2 component to host the topbar html and loaded it into my app.

Everything loads and works fine except for the .js for foundation

It doesn't seem to be getting applied to the page or component so the topbar nav has all the dropdowns just open and on display without any need for hovering.

There are no error messages in the console...is it possible the way angular 2 loads components that the foundation js just never gets bound to the html?

Comment: Are you loading the navbar later? if so you had to reinitialize the foundation js.

Comment: I have tried loading the $(document).foundation() command inside an Angular component but still no luck